# Doctrine: how to manually set an entity's MySQL timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I want to update an entity but also preserve its existing timestamp. In other words, in most cases I want this MySQL timestamp to automatically do what it's designed to do, but in certain cases I want to cheat -- sneak in an update without changing this last-modification column. Doing this manually with SQL is a piece of cake, of course:

`UPDATE events SET admin_notes = "foo", lastmod = lastmod WHERE /*...*/`

But I can't figure how to make Doctrine do this.

The entity is called `Application\Entity\Event` and the column/annotation looks like:

```
/**
 *  @ORM\Column(name="lastmod",type="datetime") 
 *  @var \DateTime
 */
protected $modified;
```

The underlying table definition, in relevant part:

`lastmod timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

So, I get a `Event` and attempt, e.g.,

```
$timestamp = $event->getModified();
echo "existing timestamp is: ".$timestamp->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')."\n";
//2016-06-07 10:13:15

$event
    ->setAdminNotes("this is an update at ".date('Y-m-d H:i:s'))
    ->setModified($timestamp);
$em->flush();
```

and this does not work. The timestamp in the in-memory entity object is "right," i.e., unchanged, but in the actual database it gets set to the current datetime as though it didn't hear what I said. Looking at the SQL log of course that's exactly the case. My `$event->setModified($timestamp)` does not make it into the generated SQL statement.

Yes, I realize I could change the table's data type to a MySQL datetime and handle it manually all over the application. Not an option right now.

For argument's sake, I tried getting the `Doctrine\DBAL\Connection` from the entity manager, and running the `executeUpdate($SQL)` myself, and discovered  (from the SQL log) that if I do it before `flush()`, it is ignored. So right now, the only thing that works is very ugly: keep the old timestamp in a variable, do a `flush()`, then run another UPDATE to manually set it back to what it was before.

Any suggestions?

Comment: thank you Denis Alimov! case closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doctrine see that you did not modify your $timestamp object, that is why it is not included in sql query. try to

```
$newTimestamp = clone $timestamp; 
$event->setModified($newTimestamp);
```